# What would happen if everyone became a monk or nun?

Tags: theravada, monastery

Theravada Buddhism holds that achieving nirvana is impossible for a lay person, hence my question.

> "When this was said, the wanderer Vacchagotta asked the Blessed One: “Master Gotama, is there any householder who, without abandoning the fetter of householdership, on the dissolution of the body has made an end of suffering?”
>
> “Vaccha, there is no householder who, without abandoning the fetter of householdership, on the dissolution of the body has made an end of suffering".
>
> - MN 71  (Tevijjavaccha-suttaṃ)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Buddhism SE. Could you provide a source for the statement; *"Theravada Buddhism holds that achieving nirvana is impossible for a lay person"*. Thank you.

Comment: Within hours of becoming an Arahant, s/he will have to leave the lay life behind and become a Bhikkhu/ni. A lay person cannot survive for long, once an Arahant, due to the overbearing power of  that state.

Comment: See also [Should a Buddhist have Children?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2403/254) which asks, "what happens if all people in the world stop having children?"

Answer (score 3):

The distinguishing principle in the quote from MN 71 is:

> *'without abandoning **the fetter** of householdership*'

I would assume (I will research later) 'the fetter' of householdship refers to concerns about & bondage to family, etc, as written in many suttas with the stock phrase:

> *...dwelling in a home crowded with children, enjoying Kasian sandalwood, wearing garments, scents and unguents, receiving good &
>   silver... [AN 8.54](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.054.than.html); [Ud 6.2](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.6.02.than.html); SN 55.7; SN 55.53*

A layperson can abandon 'the fetter' of householdership, as explained in the [Haliddakani Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.003.than.html), which describes the 'household life' is a state of mind rather than a state of physical habitation:

> *The property of form, householder, is the home of consciousness. When consciousness is in bondage through passion to the property of form,
>   it is said to be living at home. The property of feeling...
>   perception... fabrication is the home of consciousness. When
>   consciousness is in bondage through passion to the property of
>   fabrication, it is said to be dwelling at home.*
>
> *"And how does one not live at home? Any desire, passion, delight, craving, any attachments, clingings, fixations of awareness, biases,
>   or obsessions with regard to the property of form: these the Tathagata
>   has abandoned, their root destroyed, made like a palmyra stump,
>   deprived of the conditions of development, not destined for future
>   arising. Therefore the Tathagata is said to be not dwelling at home.*
>
> *"Any desire, passion, delight, craving, any attachments, clingings, fixations of awareness, biases or obsessions with regard to the
>   property of feeling... perception... fabrication...*
>
> *"Any desire, passion, delight, craving, any attachments, clingings, fixations of awareness, biases or obsessions with regard to the
>   property of consciousness: these the Tathagata has abandoned, their
>   root destroyed, made like a palmyra stump, deprived of the conditions
>   of development, not destined for future arising. Therefore the
>   Tathagata is said to be not dwelling at home.*
>
> *"And how does one live with society? One who is in bondage to the distraction of the society of form-impressions is said to be living in
>   society. One who is in bondage to the distraction of the society of
>   sound-impressions... aroma-impressions... flavor-impressions...
>   tactile-sensation-impressions... idea-impressions is said to be living
>   in society. This is how one lives with society.*
>
> *"And how does one live free from society? The Tathagata has abandoned bondage to the distraction of the society of form-impressions, its
>   root destroyed, made like a palmyra stump, deprived of the conditions
>   of development, not destined for future arising. Therefore the
>   Tathagata is said to be living free from society.*
>
> *"The Tathagata has abandoned bondage to the distraction of the society of sound-impressions... aroma-impressions...
>   flavor-impressions... tactile-sensation-impressions...
>   idea-impressions, its root destroyed, made like a palmyra stump,
>   deprived of the conditions of development, not destined for future
>   arising. Therefore the Tathagata is said to be living free from
>   society.*
>
> *"And how is one intimate in villages? There is the case where a certain person lives entangled with householders. Delighting together
>   with them, sorrowing together with them, happy when they are happy,
>   pained when they are pained, he takes on any of their arisen business
>   affairs as his own duty. This is how one is intimate in villages.*
>
> *"And how is one not intimate in villages? There is the case where a monk lives unentangled with householders. Not delighting together with
>   them, not sorrowing together with them, not happy when they are happy,
>   not pained when they are pained, he does not take on any of their
>   arisen business affairs as his own duty. This is how one is not
>   intimate in villages.*

Therefore, a layperson can end suffering (generally regarded to the degree of a Non-Returner).

Answer (score 2):

A layperson does not necessarily have to be a householder. A layperson is not necessarily  clinging to a house if they live in a house. One can hold something but still not cling to it. When I use the word "hold" here, I mean to "have something" or "feel something" or "use something" without clinging to it, like for instance, "one can have love for a parent without clinging to the parent".

Comment: Indeed. Your answer is correct. I have answered in the same way as you, however from the suttas. Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible every person to become a monk or nun.
It is same as not every person become a doctor or nurse.
Only few people have the faith and energy to become a monk or nun.