# Can not wanting to have a child be justified under the framework of Buddhism?

Tags: children

People who have children have them for the sake of their own happiness, and ultimately the child suffers.

Can we justify not having children at all even for householders stating that all life is bound to suffering?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this topic is an exact duplicate, which has some answers already.

Comment: As well as [Should a Buddhist have Children?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/should-a-buddhist-have-children), see also [Pursuit of raising children ok?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3891/254), and [Buddhist path X Romantic Relationships and Sons](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2352/254)